# express app does not get data from a html form

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

i am trying to build a messaging app and when i send the post request via a html form(its a html file) nothing happens i only saw in the network tab in firefox that i got a 204 no content response. how can i fix that? as there is no data in the db. thanks in advance!

this is my code:

app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const cors = require("cors");
const authRouter = require("./routes/authrouter");
const messagerouter = require("./routes/messages");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/market", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:"));
db.once("open", () => {
  console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
});
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/auth", authRouter);
app.use("/api", messagerouter);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.get("/send", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "send.html"));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

send.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Message Sender</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Send Message</h1>

    <form id="messageForm">
      <label for="sender">Sender:</label>
      <input type="text" id="sender" name="sender" required /><br /><br />

      <label for="recipient">Recipient:</label>
      <input type="text" id="recipient" name="recipient" required /><br /><br />

      <label for="content">content:</label>
      <textarea
        id="content"
        name="content"
        rows="4"
        cols="50"
        required
      ></textarea
      ><br /><br />

      <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
    </form>

    <script>
      document
        .getElementById("messageForm")
        .addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
          event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission

          const formData = new FormData(this);
          const data = {};
          formData.forEach((value, key) => {
            data[key] = value;
          });

          // Replace 'YOUR_API_ENDPOINT' with the actual Express API endpoint URL
          const apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/messages";

          fetch(apiUrl, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              // Add any required headers (e.g., authentication token) here
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
          })
            .then((response) => {
              if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("Network response was not ok.");
              }
              return response.json();
            })
            .then((result) => {
              console.log("Message sent:", result);
              // Optionally, do something with the response, like display a success message
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error("There was a problem sending the message:", error);
              // Handle errors, display an error message, etc.
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

authrouter.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const authRouter = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const { body } = require("express-validator");
const encryptPassword = require("../models/password");
const User = require("../models/user");

authRouter.post(
  "/register",
  [
    body("username").trim().notEmpty().withMessage("Username is required"),
    body("password")
      .trim()
      .isLength({ min: 4 })
      .withMessage("Password must be at least 4 characters"),
    body("role")
      .trim()
      .notEmpty()
      .isLength({ min: 5, max: 6 })
      .withMessage("you must select a role"),
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password, role } = req.body;

    try {
      const hashedPassword = encryptPassword(password);
      const newUser = new User({ username, password: hashedPassword, role });
      await newUser.save();
      res.status(201).json({ message: "User registered successfully" });
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    }
  }
);

authRouter.post(
  "/login",
  [
    body("username").trim().notEmpty().withMessage("Username is required"),
    body("password").trim().notEmpty().withMessage("Password is required"),
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;

    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ username });
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid username" });
      }

      const userpassword = user.password;
      const passwordMatch = encryptPassword(password);
      if (!userpassword === passwordMatch) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid password" });
      } else {
        const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, "your_secret_key", {
          expiresIn: "1h",
        });
        res.status(200).json({ token, username: user.username });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    }
  }
);

authRouter.get("/user", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.userId);

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" });
    }

    res.status(200).json({ username: user.username, role: user.role });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
});

module.exports = authRouter;
```

messages.js:

```
// messages.js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sender: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User", // Reference to the User model
    required: true,
  },
  recipient: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User", // Reference to the User model
    required: true,
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  timestamp: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

const Message = mongoose.model("message", messageSchema);

// Endpoint to get all messages
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const messages = await Message.find().populate(
      "sender recipient",
      "username"
    ); // Assuming 'sender' and 'recipient' are references to the User model
    res.json(messages);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
  }
});

// Endpoint to send a message
router.post("/messages", async (req, res) => {
  const { sender, recipient, content } = req.body;

  try {
    const newMessage = new Message({ sender, recipient, content });
    const savedMessage = await newMessage.save();
    res.status(201).json(savedMessage);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
  }
});

const checkConversationAccess = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { senderId, recipientId } = req.params;

  if (senderId !== req.user.userId && recipientId !== req.user.userId) {
    return res.status(403).json({ message: "Forbidden" });
  }

  next();
};

// Endpoint to get messages between two users
router.get("/messages/:senderId/:recipientId", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { senderId, recipientId } = req.params;
    const messages = await Message.find({
      $or: [
        { sender: senderId, recipient: recipientId },
        { sender: recipientId, recipient: senderId },
      ],
    }).populate("sender recipient", "username"); // Assuming 'sender' and 'recipient' are references to the User model
    res.json(messages);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
  }
});

module.exports = Message;
```

usermodel:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String, unique: true },
  password: String,
  role: String,
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

passwordmodel:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

function encryptPassword(password) {
  const md5Hash = crypto.createHash("md5");
  md5Hash.update(password);
  const hashedPassword = md5Hash.digest("hex");
  return hashedPassword;
}

module.exports = encryptPassword;
```